In C# Windows Service, how do I run an app before LogonUI?
I would like to achieve a similar result to BitDefender's Rescue Environment — running an interactive GUI before the login screen appears. The console app is also okay, but if Winforms (or something similar) is available, it would be better.
This all needs to be done using C#. If it's possible to do it a different way, such as registry modification, it would be even better than service.
I need it because I have to perform certain operations to the Users directory when no user is logged in as it wouldn't work when a user is logged in. It's not deletion or move, so MoveFileEx P/Invoke wouldn't work.
I tried overwriting LogonUI.exe in Virtual Machine and it worked, however, this is solution is not safe at all and I'm not gonna use it in the app for my users.

The default startup type for a Windows Service is Manual, which means the service has to be manually invoked via command line or by user. Startup type set to Automatic should start the Windows Service before LogonUI. I'm not sure if the callee (app launched from service) will run correctly by using a method like Process.Start(string) to launch the process, because the app will run under the SYSTEM profile.

I haven't tested it but you should be able to add a reference and using statement to your service code to pull in WinForms (System.Windows.Forms). Then add an Application.Run(new FormName()) as the first line in the Program constructor(Main()) of your service. This would start the Winform app and when you have finished the work in the Winform and exit, it would execute the next line to start your service. You would obviously have to start the service manually from a machine that could execute/display the WinForm.

Windows services are not supposed to interact directly with the UI. If you want something on the logon page you should use GINA or some kind of custom shell.

@Charlieface so then how does a program like Bitdefender do it?

I don't know. You might want to decompile it to find out. Possibly it spawns a new GUI application in the console session (as opposed to Session 0 which is where the service runs), or it hijacks the WinLogon bootstrapping, or even adds a Recovery Environment (similar to WinRE) or other separate compact OS (these last two the most likely). Examine the Recovery Environment you have: if you can pull up cmd with Shift+F10 and if there is a X:\ drive then it's almost certainly WinRE or a compact OS.
